# Spell Check when using string (Not Controls)

Tags: c#, string, spell-checking

Could anyone suggest some libraries or API's that is free to use and can check spelling ? I am not looking into control based libraries, but rather a method where i could pass string and know the spell errors.

Thanks

Comment: What about an [API](https://www.google.at/search?q=spell+check+api)?

Comment: @Werner That should be good. Any suggestion ?